# Длинная арифметика

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, системы-счисления

Нам дано длинное натуральное число, представленное в виде динамического массива:

1) разряды числа записываются от старшего к младшему;

2) нули до первого значащего элемента не изменяют число (т.е. массивы 52957172582 и 00052957172582 представляют одно и то же число).

Также нам даны числитель и *знаменатель несократимой обыкновенной дроби.

Задача: предложить эффективный алгоритм умножения числа на дробь (под "эффективным" понимается за один цикл, т.е. сначала умножить на числитель, а потом разделить на знаменатель нельзя).

*Знаменатель дроби либо равен 1, либо кратен 2 или(и) 5.

Comment: Домашнее задание нужно решать самостоятельно

Comment: 1) Это не домашнее задание
2) Почему-то никто его не может решить

Comment: Мда............

Comment: А что должна дать кратность знаменателя 2 или 5? И вообще, это условие неясно.

Comment: Знаменатель является степенью 10 или просто кратен?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что знаменатель может делиться _только_ на 2 и 5? Например, может быть 192?

Comment: @LEQADA, откройте вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, открыл. Будете отвечать?

Comment: с такими темпами скоро без ответа задачу не примем

Comment: @LEQADA, очередь на ответ образовалась

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, это здорово!

Comment: @ИванГрозный: А что конкретно есть ваша дробь? Какой тип данных числителя и знаменателя? Это важно.

Answer (score 1):

Речь о целочисленной десятичной арифметике, знаменатель приводится к степени 10.
Алгоритм прост как валенок:

1. Определяем последнюю ненулевую цифру знаменателя дроби.
   Если чётная, то умножаем числитель и знаменатель на 5 и повторяем операцию.
   Если 5, то умножаем на 2 и повторяем операцию.
   Если 1, то переходим к п.2.
2. Перемножаем число на числитель дроби и сдвигаем вправо на  количество нулевых десятичных разрядов в знаменателе.

Answer (score 1):

**В предположении**, что автор имел в виду «знаменатель может делиться только на 2 и 5» (иначе особенного смысла в условии не видно), можно попробовать следующий простой алгоритм:

1. Превращаем дробь в десятичную дробь. Для этого превращаем знаменатель в степень десятки следующим образом:

   - Убираем все финальные нули в знаменателе проверкой делимости на 10 и последующим делением. Запоминаем количество убранных нулей.
   - Если знаменатель получается нечётным, домножаем его и числитель на 2, возвращаемся в предыдущий подпункт (при этом уйдёт ноль из знаменателя)
   - В противном случае знаменатель чётный, домножаем его и числитель на 5 и возвращаемся в первый подпункт (при этом уйдёт ноль из знаменателя).
2. Таким образом, мы превратили знаменатель в 1, знаем число убранных нулей, а числитель превратился в число разрядности не более чем вдвое большей оригинала.
3. Теперь мы можем умножить большое число на числитель за один проход. Если старый числитель был, допустим, типа `int32_t`, новый числитель будет помещаться в `int64_t`: нам нужно взять число вдвое больше разрядности. Мы просто повторяем проход умножения в столбик, накапливая результат в новом числе. При этом умножение числа двойной «ширины» на число одинарной «ширины» будет не таким простым: если `i1` и `i2` — части числителя «одинарной» ширины, а `d` — очередная `int`-цифра длинного числа, то умножение будет иметь вид

   ```
                   i1   i2
       c1    c2   ........
   -----------------------
                     i2*c2
                  i2*c1
                  i1*c2
             i1*c1
   ```

   и т. д. На каждом шаге цикла по разрядам длинного числа вы будете прибавлять по два слагаемых.
4. Не забываем поставить на правильное место десятичную запятую после окончания умножения.

Comment: Обыкновенная дробь не обязана иметь двухразрядный числитель. Откуда он взялся?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Я имел в виду `int` под разрядом, а под двухразрядным числителем — число, содержащее вдвое больше разрядов, чем `int`. Исправлю текст.

Comment: Про формат "обыкновенной дроби" вообще ничего не сказано, да и мы с Вами не спросили. На мой взгляд, это не самый существенный момент - да хоть те же десятичные числа большой точности (я про формат PHP), лишь бы не делить.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Это да, стоит переспросить.

Comment: У нас лишь одно конкретное указание: "под "эффективным" понимается за один цикл, т.е. сначала умножить на числитель, а потом разделить на знаменатель нельзя"

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Я предположил, что это означает, что числитель и знаменатель не «длинные». Иначе за линейное время не получится.

Comment: Поскольку число длинное по сравнению с дробью, то экономия на делении - уже достаточное условие эффективности, или "линейности".